# Logging into instagram using Python requests

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests, instagram

I'm trying to log into Instagram using Python Requests. I figured it would be as simple as creating a `requests.Session` object and then sending a post request i.e.

```
session.post(login_url, data={'username':****, 'password':****})
```

This didn't work. I didn't know why so I tried manually entering the browsers headers (I used Chrome dev tools to see the headers of the post request) and passing them along with the request (`headers={...}`) even though I figured the session would deal with that. I tried sending a get request to the login URL first in order to get a cookie (and CSRF token I think) then doing the steps mentioned before. None of this worked.

I dont have much experience at all with this type of thing and I just dont understand what differentiates my post requests from google chromes (I must be doing something wrong). Thanks

Comment: What url are you using for the login?

Comment: ive tried https://www.instagram.com/ and https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax (which is the url that chrome sent the request i think)

Comment: I guess you don't want to use the official api...have a look here btw:
https://github.com/LevPasha/instabot.py/blob/master/src/instabot.py#L206

Comment: yeah i was trying to avoid that as i wanted to practice the basics

Comment: If you don't want to use their API, you might want to download `fiddler` to capture all traffic while logging into instagram with Chrome, then simulate all related requests (especially header part), you are good to go.